# Python - split string into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, split, tuples

My situation is following.
I have a sting "list" like this

```
Text1
Text2: value1
Text3:
Text4:
Text5: value2
...
```

Now I want to split the text into a dictionary with Key-Value Pair.

I tryed it with this 1liner

```
sp = dict(s.split(':') for s in list.split('\n') if len(s) > 1 and s.count(':') > 0)
```

This works great until there is no value like in Text3 and Text4.

My final dictionary should look like this

```
{ Text2:value1,Text3:'',Text4:'',Text5:value2 }
```

Text1 should be skipped - but Text3 & Text4 I need in the dictionary, also if the value is empty.

Comment: I'm getting the expected output which you have mentioned. It has skipped Text1

Comment: yes, i too am getting your expected output.

Comment: Your code works in python2.7 and 3.5. Do not use `list` keyword for a variable. Instead of doing `s.count(':') > 0`, you can just do `':' in s`

Comment: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #75 has length 3; 2 is required - I use python 3.6

Comment: I found the issue causing this problem - I have one Element with

Key:http:// xyz .com

This would get split in 3 parts - so how can I skip such lines with more than 2 Elements ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your case `Key:http:// xyz .com` you have to stop the [split](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) after the first match using `s.split(':', 1))`:

```
my_str = """Text1
Text2: value1
Text3:
Text4:
Text5: value2
Key:http:// xyz .com 
"""

sp = dict(map(str.strip, s.split(':', 1)) for s in my_str.split('\n') if ':' in s)
print(sp)
```

output:

```
{'Text2': 'value1', 'Text3': '', 'Text4': '', 'Text5': 'value2', 'Key': 'http:// xyz .com'}
```

Comment: you edited the message, while I was writing the answer I found - thanks for your support !

Answer (score 1):

Because of this issue, which I only found with the help of comments, I could solve the problem this way

```
my_str = """Text1
Text2: value1
Text3:
Text4:
Text5: value2
Text6:http: // something
"""
```

The problem was, that the last row was split in 3 parts because of the webadress in the value field.

```
sp = dict(s.split(':') for s in my_str.split('\n') if len(s) > 1 and s.count(':') == 1)
```

Maybe there is a nicer way, but I checked if the split char ":" only accours 1 time - because then I am sure to get a pair, I can insert into the dictionary :)